# simulating centipede finite state machine

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, fsm

I'm trying to write a centipede game clone, and I have written a node class which is basically a circle. 
I'm trying to write an FSM to simulate node movements and bouncing with bricks or the screen, but the problem, that the FSM conflicts with other conditions. How would I resolve it ? For example one of the nodes can be at x <0 but they have y > 800.

```
public function gameLoop(event:Event):void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < m_nodes.length; i++)
        {

            if (m_nodes[i].x > 750)
            {
                m_nodes[i].current_dir = Node.Direction_RIGHT;

            }
            else  if (m_nodes[i].x < 10)
            {

                m_nodes[i].current_dir = Node.Direction_UP;

            }

            if ( m_nodes[i].y < 0 )
            {
                m_nodes[i].current_dir = Node.Direction_RIGHT;

            }


            else if ( m_nodes[i].y > 590 )
            {
                m_nodes[i].current_dir =Node.Direction_LEFT;
            }




            if (m_nodes[i].hitTestObject(m_bricks[i]))
            {

                //m_nodes[i].current_dir = Node.Direction_RIGHT; 

            }

            if (m_nodes[i].current_dir == Node.Direction_LEFT)
            {
                m_nodes[i].vx = -5;
                m_nodes[i].vy = 0;
            }

            if (m_nodes[i].current_dir == Node.Direction_RIGHT)
            {

                m_nodes[i].vx = 0;
                m_nodes[i].vy = 5;
            }

             if (m_nodes[i].current_dir == Node.Direction_UP)
            {

                m_nodes[i].vx = 0;
                m_nodes[i].vy = -5;
            }

            m_nodes[i].x += m_nodes[i].vx;
            m_nodes[i].y += m_nodes[i].vy;


        }

    }
```

Update:  new updated code, with fixing the logic, but collision detects fails, the state machines have conflict states.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < m_nodes.length; i++)
        {

            if (m_nodes[i].x > 750)
            {
                m_nodes[i].current_dir = Node.Direction_DOWN;

            }
            else if (m_nodes[i].x < 40 && m_nodes[i].y < 600)
            {
                if (!m_nodes[i].current_dir == Node.Direction_RIGHT)
                {
                    m_nodes[i].current_dir = Node.Direction_UP;
                    trace("dir up");
                }

            }


            if (m_nodes[i].hitTestObject(m_bricks[i]) )
            {
                trace("hit");
                m_nodes[i].vx = 0;
                m_nodes[i].vy = 5;
            }



            if (m_nodes[i].y < 40 && m_nodes[i].x < 40)
            {
                m_nodes[i].current_dir = Node.Direction_RIGHT;

            }

            else if (m_nodes[i].y > 560 && m_nodes[i].x > 40)
            {
                m_nodes[i].current_dir = Node.Direction_LEFT;
            }

            if (m_nodes[i].current_dir == Node.Direction_LEFT)
            {
                m_nodes[i].vx = -5;
                m_nodes[i].vy = 0;
            }

            else if (m_nodes[i].current_dir == Node.Direction_DOWN)
            {

                m_nodes[i].vx = 0;
                m_nodes[i].vy = 5;
            }
            else if (m_nodes[i].current_dir == Node.Direction_RIGHT)
            {

                m_nodes[i].vx = 5;
                m_nodes[i].vy = 0;
            }

            if (m_nodes[i].current_dir == Node.Direction_UP)
            {

                m_nodes[i].vx = 0;
                m_nodes[i].vy = -5;
            }

            m_nodes[i].x += m_nodes[i].vx;
            m_nodes[i].y += m_nodes[i].vy;


        }
```

Comment: There seems to be some confusion regarding right, left, up. For example, when you are looking at the boundarys, if x is too large you switch direction to right, but if x is too small you shift direction to up. Is that really what you want to do? Then when you get to actually move your sprite, you choose to decrement x if moving left, but increment y when moving right.

Comment: I want when the snake bounces the right edge, it goes down, and left when it bounces the upper edge of the window,..etc. I also have a problem that the Node.Direction_UP is never executed, because it conflicts with other state, which state Left, because Y is large at that time

Comment: I would need a better idea of exactly what 'kinematic' behavior you want to exhibit, but if you have conflicting states when you just look at x and y coordinates separately, then possibly you cant determine the state by looking at x and y independently. Instead you may need to determine your state transitions by looking at x and y simultaneously. For example if x < p and y < q then state = x_low_and_y_low_state (etc.).

Comment: that's what I have figured out just 2 mins ago, thanks :). would project euler helps me to solve logical problems like that for a self taught programmer ?

Comment: I fixed it, but I have problem with the collision detection, the logic still breaks and there are conflicts. Please would you take a look at the updated code?

Comment: I will write my comments as an answer - not a full answer, but the comments space is probably insufficient.